# How to restrict access to specific pages on the back-end?

Tags: user-roles, capabilities

Before anything... I understand how roles and capabilities work. And there are tons of plugins that help you manage those. Roles and capabilities can only be so specific though. Is there "wordpress way" of restricting access to specific pages/posts ids in the admin? Does wordpress have any functionality built-in? (I know there's no UI).

Comment: Good question. From my exprience I'd say no it's not possible. Have you thinking about alternative solution, keeping ID's in user metafield + conditional logic to hide posts? Or you're looking for UI core-solution if it exists?

Comment: I was looking to use some functionality that's built-in. But I can't find any.

Comment: For 4 years never met this feature build-into wp. I suggest only plugins or custom code solutions here. Will keep question tracked.